# replace unique, noninteger varchar with unique integer in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, casting

I have a postgres table 'labs' with two columns (col1 varchar, col2 varchar).

```
col1   |  col2
1.2.3  |   a
1.2.3  |   b
3.4.4  |   c
3.4.4  |   d
2.6.9  |   e
2.6.9  |   f
```

I would like to replace col1 with an integer like this

```
col1   |  col2
1  |   a
1  |   b
2  |   c
2  |   d
3  |   e
3  |   f
```

Does anyone know an efficient statement to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a `select` query using:

```
select dense_rank() over (order by col1) as col1, col2
```

This doesn't produce exactly the results you want (it would be 1, 3, 2).  SQL tables represent unordered sets.  Your data doesn't have enough information to assign the second value a value of "2" rather than "3".

You can also incorporate this into an `update`, but that wouldn't be recommended because the current value is a string and the result you want is an integer.